# ConfigurationManager .net Core 2.0(C#) в консоли

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, .net-core

Пишу простую консольную программу в академических целях. В ней присутствует база данных MSSQL c одной таблицей. Посредством ADO.NET в ней я делаю простые операции CRUD. Сейчас я хочу сделать то же самое, только использовать .NET Core. Проблема возникла с пространством имен.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Так же проблема со строкой подключения:

```
static string DBaddress = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConection"].ConnectionString;
```

Соответственно код который был написан ранее в стандартном консольном приложении

```
  // Connection handler for all classes;
    private static bool NonQuery(SqlCommand comm)
    {
        int result = -1;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBaddress))
        {
            comm.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return (result == 1)?true:false;
    }

 // Read from DB;
    public static List<Users> ReadDataFromDB()
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBaddress))
        {
            List<Users> users = new List<Users>();
            string select = "SELECT * FROM Users";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select, con);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    users.Add(new Users(Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]), reader["FirstName"].ToString(), reader["LastName"].ToString()));
                }
            }

           catch
            {

            }

            return users;
        }
    }
```

теперь не работает.

Comment: Как я понимаю, .NET Core -  это другие сборки, с переписанным с нуля кодом, и, конечно, там есть отличия с классическим asp.net. Раз вы занимаетесь в академических целях, советую изучить .NET Core и поправить ваш код самостоятельно

Comment: В .Net Core2 вроде как добавили Configuration Manager. А вообще да, раньше там был другой механизм для строки подключения. В этом случае я не использую технологию ASP.NET, у меня классическое консольное приложение. Спасибо за наводку, почитал туториал на MSDN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема решена установкой Nuget пакетов

1. System.Configuration;
2. System.Data.SqlClient;
3. System.Data.Common